# Subroutines in batch files

Tags: batch-file

Given the following code:

```
@Echo off
ECHO Start
ECHO Calling SUB_A
CALL :SUB_A
ECHO Calling SUB_B
CALL :SUB_B

:SUB_A
    ECHO In SUB_A
    GOTO:EOF

:SUB_B
    ECHO In SUB_B
    GOTO:EOF

ECHO End
```

I expect this output:

```
Start
Calling SUB_A
In SUB_A
Calling SUB_B
In SUB_B
End
```

But I get this:

```
Start
Calling SUB_A
In SUB_A
Calling SUB_B
In SUB_B
In SUB_A
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The line `CALL :SUB_B` returns, the script proceeds to the next few lines:

```
:SUB_A           # no effect from this one
ECHO In SUB_A    # prints message
```

You need to insert a `GOTO:EOF` after the call if you want it to stop there.

Batch files are not structured programs; they are a sequence of instructions with some BASIC-like facility for GOTO and CALL.

Answer (score 69):

If you want to return from a CALL, you use EXIT command with /B argument (as "EXIT" alone will terminate the batch file).

For example:

```
CALL :SUB_ONE
CALL :SUB_TWO

GOTO :EOF

:SUB_ONE
ECHO Hello from one
EXIT /B

:SUB_TWO
ECHO Hello from two
EXIT /B

:EOF
```

Comment: I find this preferable to `goto :EOF` as you can add a return value as ERRORLEVEL: `exit /B %RetVal%`

Comment: One note - you should not define `EOF` label. `GOTO :EOF` works out of the box. Also note that you are calling `:EOF` and you can only define `EOF` which would be called by `GOTO EOF`.

Comment: Need to have the colon after the 'CALL' and before the 'subroutine' name. I've never had to use them before, but did here and it worked after that.

Answer (score 6):

After your line `CALL :SUB_B` the batch file falls through to SUB_A.  If you don't want it to, you need to put a `GOTO` line there.

Answer (score 2):

Just to stick my $0.02 worth in here:

I would have to say that DOS files (or DOS batch files) should always be written as :

```
[ Main Program ]

EXIT

[ All Subroutines ]
```

In this way - you can never fall into the subroutine section.

Also - always use REM statements before, during, and possibly after each section so you always know what a section is going to do.

And last - but not least - See if you can write a batch file so it becomes more generic so you can set it to one side and use it when you need to again.

Just my $0.02 worth of common sense you probably already know. :-)

OH! Sorry! Forgot to post my small sleeper subroutine I wrote. Here it is! :-)

```
REM
REM Calling the Sleeper subroutine
REM
call :sleeper
exit

REM
REM Sleeper subroutine
REM
REM qna = Questions and Answers
REM
REM Interestingly - you can NOT use a '>'
REM Because DOS uses it for redirection!
REM Instead - use a question mark (?)
REM
:sleeper
set /p qna=Press return to continue or 'q' to stop ?
if [%qna%] == [q] (
    echo Exiting....please wait.
    exit
    )

goto :eof
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use EXIT!

Example:

```
@rem a.bat
@echo off
echo a.bat
timeout /t 1

call b.bat

call c.bat
```

```
@rem b.bat
@echo off
echo b.bat
timeout /t 1

call :subB
rem call to c.bat will fail if using "exit" instead of "goto :end"
goto :end

:subB
echo subB
timeout /t 1
exit /b

:end
```

```
@rem c.bat
@echo off
echo c.bat
timeout /t 1
```

"exit" immediately aborts the call chain!

Comment: It's already explained with more details by aikeru ten years ago. And it's superfluous to use a label named `:end`, there exists always the implicit label `:eof`